# parallel read a python shelve object

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to parallelize the following for-loop that reads from a shelved python object

```
result = []
for k in my_keys:
    val = my_shelved_db[k]
    result.append(val)
```

where : `my_shelved_db = shelve.open('my_file.db')`

Can someone give an example how this could be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Manager

manager = Manager()
result = manager.list()

def func(k):
    val = my_shelved_db[k]
    result.append(val)

# my_keys = range(10)

for  k in my_keys:
    process = multiprocessing.Process(target=func,args=(k,))
    process.start()


print(result)
```